# DXA 2.2 inherited Structure Group metadata to Page

Tags: dxa, content-manager, dxa2.2

I've added Structure Group metadata and in the DXA version previous to 2.0 there was a TBB to add inherited metadata.  This seems to be the default behavior of DXA 2+ however it does not show up in the JSON output.  Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?  I have the following TBB's in my Page Template.

```
<CompoundTemplate xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.3/CompoundTemplate">
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:2-53-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Render Page Content" />
    <TemplateParameters />
  </TemplateInvocation>
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:2-54-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Default Page Template Finish Actions" />
    <TemplateParameters />
  </TemplateInvocation>
</CompoundTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder` in your Model Builder Pipeline. In your case, the pipeline is a parameter of the `Render Page Content` TBB. See [here](https://docs.sdl.com/784837/684143/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/model-builder-pipeline)

Comment: Thanks Atila that works!